# Json Logql query for getting multiple line graphs grouping by a single json key

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

new to logql here.

This is a sample json log line I have:

```
{
"accessedts":1696477777255,
"command":"get_user_details",
"country":"US",
"referrer":"google",
"status":"SUCCESS",
}
```

I am trying to write a simple logql query which will give me multiple line graphs,
each representing the rate for a country (grouping by the country field. there would be mulitiple countries in the logs) and doing the
same for the referrer.

So the end expectation would be to have a line graph per country which represents the rate.

I was trying something like this (but did not work):

`sum by (country) (rate({namespace="mynamespace"}| json | __error__!="JSONParserErr"[10m]))`

I can see all my logs when I query for {namespace="mynamespace"} in the explorer.

Would you know how I could write a query for this ?

Comment: Your query looks fine. Check that all fields are correct, and that your actual selector returns expected data before aggregation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by did not work? Did you get unexpected results, or no results?

Comment: I just get back no data, while running - rate({namespace="mynamespace"}[1m]) works perfectly fine

Comment: Does `{namespace="mynamespace"}| json` return data? And if yes, is `country` label among returned data?